Does C++ automatically downcast in order to find the right virtual function?
Question Polymorphism, Downcasting, and Virtual Functions seems vague and I'm not sure whether it's the same or a different question. One answer seems to answer my question (yes), but to make sure it's succinct. Here's my example.
class BaseClass {
public:
   virtual int myFunc() {
      return 0;
   }
};

class DerivedClass : BaseClass {
public:
   virtual int myFunc() {
      return 1;
   }
};

main() {
   DerivedClass* dclass = new DerivedClass;
   BaseClass* thinkImBaseClass = dclass;
   cout << "myFunc returns " <<  thinkImBaseClass->myFunc() << endl;
}

Does some runtime calculation discover that thinkImBaseClass is really DerivedClass? Or does the programmer have to cast it so the compiler knows at compile time:
((DerivedClass*)thinkImBaseClass)->myFunc();


A cast is an explicit type conversion. "Automatic downcast" is nonsense. What is unclear in the accepted answer? "The program will use run-time information (so-called "virtual table") to determine which virtual function to call". More concise and to the point does not exist. "Does some runtime calculation discover that thinkImBaseClass is really DerivedClass?" Yes, the program uses run-time information (so-called "virtual table") to determine that. "Or does the programmer have to..." Did you have to do that?

The question says "... when circle is downcast to shape ..." The answer says, "... the program will use run-time information ...". It doesn't say, "... that run-time information would be for the derived class ... created from when the class was constructed ... so you don't need to downcaste". I figure the community may want a question that says, what happens if you DON'T downcaste, not what happens if you DO downcaste.

Questions are asked by people who have incomplete information, so occasional misuse of terminology and downright nonsense is expected. This is true about your question and the referenced question as well. Look at the answer. "This will be done with a total disregard to your down/up-casting" Does this answer your question? If not, why not?

Suggestion: When writing code for a question, make sure it is valid (unless you are actually asking about how to make it valid).  There are numerous faults in your current example, one if which is that one of the most central things in the question, BaseClass* thinkImBaseClass = dclass;, is invalid.

@n. m. could be an AI. I'd rather it said "This will get the same result with a total disregard to your down/up-casting". I figured I'd use a coding example that left no wiggle room. But, of course we agree 95%. I cited it b/c I was 95% sure it did answer my question, just not 100% sure and the question was convoluted. But OK I take your tip about looking at the answers, not the questions.

What output did you see with cout << "myFunc returns " <<  thinkImBaseClass->myFunc() << endl;?  (You should have seen that the code provided does not compile.)

You are asking a wrong question. See, if you understand why virtual functions are needed (what problem they solve), the question simply doesn't arise as the answer is blindingly obvious. And if you don't understand the why, knowing the how doesn't help you one bit. But yes, that answer answers 100% of the wrong question you are asking.

And lo, amidst the picking and needling, nevertheless a reasonable answer was given and upvoted. Also "numerous faults" appears to be just one, the "private" inheritance.

The question that I site as a possible answer definitely doesn't compile. It says something about "abstract". That question has 1 vote this question has -1 vote, go figure.

@n. m. could be an AI sometimes you clarify the theory by isolating a simple  boolean question. Then when you get that answer, you say, "OK now I know the niche these things fill." Just think if everyone knew everything before they started programming then stack overflow would only be for algorithm exchange.

If you asked "why people need/use virtual functions", that would be a theory-clarifying question. Because the answer to that is "in order to be able to call the right function without knowing the exact type". See? This contains the answer to your question. The programmer doesn't need to know the exact type, otherwise virtual functions simply would have no reason to exist. But no, you chose to ask what you have asked. I suspect that's because you are trying to learn C++ from a wrong source and/or read the chapters in a wrong order. But whatever works for you.

@Ted Lyngmo I didn't say "compile" and neither did you. Numerous means great in number, so perhaps you mean "multiple". I'll give you main() not having a return value as a fault, even if compilers only throw a warning. In any case, the line you mentioned as being critically invalid is valid.

@n. m. could be an AI I earned a living on c++ for decades after doing assembler. I have a c++ product on the market that's installed on most PCs. But I moved on and did a few products in c, c#, objective-c, swift, Java, Javascript/jQuery, php, MySQL and Go. For all of which I have products currently on the market. I kind of had to re-straighten this out in my mind. Every example I found had the guy using a pointer to the derived class. Nobody had stated the answer the way you do in your comment. If everyone was as clear and concise as you are then I would be able to ask the way you suggest.

@TedLyngmo Clearly the OP wasn't intending to give you a whole program and I didn't need a whole program to answer the question. What did you need to compile it for, exactly?

@DaveMay It's well described in [mre]. Its for askers to present information well. I know bughunting from imperfect information, but, asking for help witholding info is not a good idea.

@DaveMay Apart from the upvote I gave you for "I didn't need a whole program" there is no reason to not encourage people to present their issues well. I'm pretty sure 99% of the C++ audience would be able to depickle this too, but that's beside the point. SO is not a competetive programming site a.f.a.i.k. It's also not a site for guessing games. Even if you happen to get it right, it's not what a Q&A is supposed to be in the long run.

Your program will do a vtable (virtual table) lookup at runtime to call the function from the derived class. It knows to do this because you declared the function as virtual in the base class.
Objects of either class will contain a hidden vpointer, a pointer to a vtable for the class it was constructed as. The vtable contains a set of pointers to the actual virtual functions for the class.

Your program will do a vtable (virtual table) lookup isn't quite right. It's right for all practical cases you're likely to encounter in the wild, but there are some pretty neat, and sometimes really weird, alternatives to the vtable. C++ doesn't specify how you do polymorphism, just what the results must be, so it could be implemented with something as esoteric as level 17 Elven Sorcery and still be compliant.

Well, it's fair to say that's the case with just about everything with modern compilers, not just vtables. I aim to provide the general idea of what happens, say, when most compilers encounter code and can't make assumptions. I would even venture to say most compilers are using witchcraft most of the time, not just sometimes.

You just rediscovered Clarke's Third Law

If compiler can resolve a concrete type it doesn't need to generate an indirect call. On the other hand, if memory doesn't fail me, there was a Borland compiler that had multiple indirections for multiple inheritance to reduce the table sizes.
